# loop through subdirectories in batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch with the following code:

```
SET CI=MySubDir
SET CIDIR=SomePath\..\..\%CI%
SET OutDir=MyOutDir

for /f %%G in ('dir /b %CIDIR%') do (
    SET SCHEMADIR=%CIDIR%\%%G\schema
    SET CATDIR=%CIDIR%\%%G\catalog

    echo %%G
    echo %SCHEMADIR%
    echo %CATDIR%
    if exist %SCHEMADIR% (
        echo copy "%SCHEMADIR%" to "%OutDir%\..\Schema"
        XCOPY /E /Y /I /Q /D %SCHEMADIR% "%OutDir%\..\Schema"
    )

    if exist %CATDIR% (
        echo copy "%CATDIR%" to "%Outdir%\..\Catalog"
        XCOPY /E /Y /I /Q /D %CATDIR% "%OutDir%\..\Catalog"
    )
)
```

This program should copy all files within any sub-directory of `SCHEMADIR` or `CATDIR` to my `OutDir` (of course the files within my `OutDir` might be overridden several times depending on the existing ones within the source-directories).

When I echo the current file-name with `echo %%G` I get the sub-directory as wanted, curiously echoing either `SCHEMADIR` or `CATDIR` results in only the very last sub-directory found within `CIDIR`. So while `%%G`results in e.g. BE, `SCHEMADIR` results to `SomePath\..\..\MySubDir\TH` (where TH is the last sub-directory within MySubDir). What is whrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch files, each line or block of lines (code inside parenthesis) is parsed, executed and the process repeated for the next line/block. During the parse phase, all variable reads are removed, being replaced with the value in the variable **before** the code starts to execute. If a variable changes its value inside the line/block, this changed value can not be retrieved from inside the same line/block as the variable read operation does not exist.

The usual way to solve it is to use delayed expansion. When enabled, you can change (where needed) the syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the command that uses the value starts to execute.

You can try this code to see it in action

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set "test=initial value"
    for %%a in (a b c) do (
        rem Variable changed inside the block of code
        set "test=%%a"

        rem Retrieve data with normal expansion 
        echo Normal expansion:  [%%a] [%test%]

        rem Retrieve data with delayed expansion
        echo Delayed expansion: [%%a] [!test!]
    )
```

In your case, since `SCHEMADIR` and `CATDIR` are changed **inside** the block of code, to retrieve the changed value **inside the same block** you will need delayed expansion.

Comment: Woah, much thanks for this, this took my a whole day.